# Only column gallery on mobile device

Tags: css, gallery, mobile

I have a portfolio with a 3 column gallery in my Brix theme in Wordpress. The website is alanllontopfotografia.com

But in mobile devices i see 2 columns, and i want to see the gallery item in one column. I have try to add different CSS but it doesn't work.

¿Can someone help me? Thank you so much.